# Entries disappearing from ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: .net, caching, singleton, concurrentdictionary

I host an API that keeps track of accounts permissions. The permissions are stored in the APIs database. In order to be able to accurately respond in case the database is extremely slow or unavailable I've chosen to attempt to the reflect the databases permissions in memory.

To do this I've selected `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Permission>`. The key is an account id and the value is it's permissions. This is wrapped in a service `InMemoryStorageService` that is registered as a singleton in our DI framework.

To be able to reflect the database in memory, the following steps are taken:

1. On application startup, the entire database table is preloaded into memory (roughly 100k entries)
2. When changes are made to an accounts permissions, they are updated in the database as well as in the in memory store

The problem I have is that, for a few percentages of the calls to the api, the permissions in memory cannot be found whereas they exist in the database. I've added logging so I know for a fact that the permissions for the specific account was loaded from the database upon start up. This occurrs rather frequently starting right after the API is started. So the order of events goes something like this:

1. Api starts
2. Permissions for accounts (123, 144, 168) are loaded into the ConcurrentDictionary
3. Account 144 attempts to get it's permissions
4. Log entry that permissions for account 144 cannot be found in memory but is present in the database

Any suggestions?

```
public class InMemoryStorageService : IInMemoryStorageService
{
    private readonly ILogFactory _logFactory;
    private readonly IPermissionRepository _permissionRepository;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Permission> _inMemoryStore;

    private ILog _log;
    protected ILog Log => _log ?? (_log = _logFactory.GetLogger(GetType()));

    public InMemoryStorageService(ILogFactory logFactory, IPermissionRepository permissionRepository)
    {
        _logFactory = logFactory;
        _permissionRepository = permissionRepository;
        _inMemoryStore = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Permission>();
    }

    public Permission GetPermission(string accountId)
    {
        Permission value;
        if (_inMemoryStore.TryGetValue(accountId, out value)) return value;

        return null;
    }

    public void AddOrUpdatePermission(Permission permissions)
    {
        if (permissions == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(permissions));

        _inMemoryStore.AddOrUpdate(permissions.AccountId, permissions,
            (accId, currentPermissions) =>
                permissions.Updated > currentPermissions?.Updated ? permissions : currentPermissions);
    }

    public void PreloadStorageFromDb()
    {
        try
        {
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            int addedPermissions = 0;
            var permissions = _permissionRepository.GetAll();
            foreach (var accountPermission in permissions)
            {
                AddOrUpdatePermission(accountPermission);
                addedPermissions++;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();
            Log.InfoAsJson($"{nameof(PreloadStorageFromDb)}", new
            {
                addedPermissions,
                timeToLoadCacheInMilliseconds = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.ErrorAsJson($"{nameof(PreloadStorageFromDb)}", null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

DI framework is SimpleInjector

```
container.RegisterInstance<IInMemoryStorageService>(new InMemoryStorageService(logFactory, new PermissionRepository(appSettings, logFactory)));
```

The api is self hosted via Owin. It is booted through a .NET Framework 4.7.1 WindowsService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I was stupid. I had assumed that the logged entries were from the api. But they originated from the engine, which does not preload the in memory store.

Apologies!